# how to update subcategory in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have Category and Products, Category has many product in it. I'm able to Edit Delete Create the Category, Also able to Create Delete Products in the Each Category, but want to Edit the each Product. 
I can access the single Product of particular Category by using link_to , and product controller is receiving the the product of particular Category.

In html of Category where all Product belongs of that category has

```
 <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_product_path(product.category, product) %>
```

Controller of Product, edit function is

```
@product = Product.where(params[:id])
```

then my edit html is

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
<% if @product.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from     being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
 <% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :description %><br />
<%= f.text_area :description %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :price %><br />
<%= f.text_field :price %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', category_products_path %>
```

I'm getting this error when try to Edit the product

```
NoMethodError in Products#edit

Showing C:/Sites/propoolpro6/app/views/products/edit.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <h1>Editing product</h1>
2: 
3: <%= form_for @product do |f| %>
4:   <% if @product.errors.any? %>
5:     <div id="error_explanation">
6:       <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product   from being saved:</h2>
Rails.root: C:/Sites/propoolpro6

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
 app/views/products/edit.html.erb:3:in  `_app_views_products_edit_html_erb___584392485_32651052'
Request

Parameters:

{"category_id"=>"1",
"id"=>"3"}
```

**Note:** i have used this 2, but same error,

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following line create array
**@product = Product.where(params[:id])**

which could not be used by the form_helper (expecting a Model name generally provided by an ActiveRecord Relation).you can inspect the @product to see the result.

so it is better if you use find instead of where like

**@product = Product.find(params[:id])**

I hope this answer would help you.
Thanks.

Comment: i have tried, now error **undefined method `product_path' for #<#<Class:0x3e43a50>:0x3e50740>**

Comment: please clarify when you got this error either clicking edit link or clicking back link?